# Python if statement trouble, possibly due to operators

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

It's late here and maybe my brain just isn't working, but I'm having a problem defining a function that takes the final grade of a student and assigns a letter grade to it.

```
def getlettergrade(fgrade): 
    if fgrade <= 59:
        return 'F'
     elif fgrade <= 69 and >= 60:
        return 'D'
     elif fgrade <= 79 and >= 70:
        return 'C'
     elif fgrade <= 89 and >= 80:
       return 'B'
     elif fgrade <= 100 and >= 90:
        return 'A'
```

The intent is to have that map to a pandas series object from a dataframe and put the output to a matplotlib graph, if that's relevant at all.

Answer (score 2):

I modified your function, there were indentation errors and the comparison where missing `fgrade` in all `elif`

```
import seaborn as sns

def getlettergrade(fgrade):
    if fgrade <= 59:
        return 'F'
    elif fgrade <= 69 and fgrade >= 60:
        return 'D'
    elif fgrade <= 79 and fgrade >= 70:
        return 'C'
    elif fgrade <= 89 and fgrade >= 80:
        return 'B'
    elif fgrade <= 100 and fgrade >= 90:
        return 'A'

temp = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(100, 100), columns=['grades'])
temp['grade_number'] = temp['grades'].apply(getlettergrade)

sns.countplot(x=temp['grade_number'])
```

This would be a sample count plot using seaborn

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Its very Simple, All you need is to edit the condition 
for example
`elif fgrade <= 69 and fgrade >= 60:` instead of `elif fgrade <= 69 and >= 60:`

Comment: Ha! That definitely worked. Thanks for the easy fix, I guess my brain just hasn't been working correctly after doing this for so many hours today. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

As Islam Hanafi pointed out, you miss the first term of the ">=" comparison.

```
elif fgrade <= 69 and >= 60:
```

becomes:

```
elif fgrade <= 69 and fgrade >= 60:
```

But you can also concatenate operators, like this:

```
elif 60 <= fgrade <= 69:
```

which, in my opinion, is slightly more readable.

Finally, you can also simplify conditions and use strict operators, to deal also with decimal grades:

```
def getlettergrade(fgrade):
    if fgrade < 60:
        return 'F'
    elif fgrade < 70:
        return 'D'
    elif fgrade < 80:
        return 'C'
    elif fgrade < 90:
        return 'B'
    else:
        return 'A'
```

(but, where is 'E'???)

Answer (score 0):

you can't compare a grade with none. Try this one

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def getlettergrade(fgrade): 
    if fgrade <= 59:
        return 'F'
    elif 60 <= fgrade <= 69:
        return 'D'
    elif 70 <= fgrade <= 79 :
        return 'C'
    elif  80 <= fgrade <= 89:
       return 'B'
    elif 90 <= fgrade <= 100:
        return 'A'

nums = np.random.choice(100, 100)
grades = pd.DataFrame(nums, columns=['fgrades'])
plt.plot(grades)
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5MMd.png)